# Unable to start PostgreSQL service after pgAgent installation

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgagent

I had Postgre running just fine on my Windows 10 (64-bit).

Then I tried to install pgAgent via the stackbuilder for postgres. I got some error that it was not able to create a .conf file under `%\user\appdata\postgres`.

(Note That folder has never existed. I had my data under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data`)

After that is asked me to restart my PC, so I did.

Now I am not able to start pgAdmin, not able to start postgre from microsoft services. I am not either able to run the stack builder for postgres, it simply suggest that it might help to reinstall postgres.

Can one stackbuilder install really corrupt my entire database?

I got these messages in the logger:

```
2019-09-10 15:33:03.300 EEST [146960] ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/share/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory
2019-09-10 15:33:03.300 EEST [146960] STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION pgagent;
2019-09-10 15:35:23.957 EEST [118560] ERROR:  could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/share/extension/pgagent.control": No such file or directory
2019-09-10 15:35:23.957 EEST [118560] STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION pgagent;
2019-09-10 15:43:44.944 EEST [152352] ERROR:  schema "pgagent" does not exist
2019-09-10 15:43:44.944 EEST [152352] STATEMENT:  SELECT has_schema_privilege('pgagent', 'USAGE')
2019-09-10 15:48:53.247 EEST [152560] ERROR:  schema "pgagent" does not exist
2019-09-10 15:48:53.247 EEST [152560] STATEMENT:  SELECT has_schema_privilege('pgagent', 'USAGE')
2019-09-10 15:51:53.369 EEST [146440] ERROR:  schema "pgagent" does not exist
2019-09-10 15:51:53.369 EEST [146440] STATEMENT:  SELECT has_schema_privilege('pgagent', 'USAGE')
2019-09-10 15:59:04.716 EEST [152972] ERROR:  schema "pgagent" does not exist
2019-09-10 15:59:04.716 EEST [152972] STATEMENT:  SELECT has_schema_privilege('pgagent', 'USAGE')
2019-09-10 16:17:15.856 EEST [151636] LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
2019-09-10 16:17:15.857 EEST [151792] LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
2019-09-10 16:17:26.569 EEST [14320] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-09-10 16:17:26.575 EEST [18252] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2019-09-10 16:17:26.576 EEST [18188] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2019-09-10 16:17:26.580 EEST [14320] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-09-10 16:17:26.580 EEST [20960] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2019-09-10 16:17:26.609 EEST [14320] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 18252) exited with exit code 1
2019-09-10 16:17:26.609 EEST [14320] LOG:  background worker "TimescaleDB Background Worker Launcher" (PID 18188) exited with exit code 1
2019-09-10 16:17:26.610 EEST [14320] LOG:  background worker "TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler" (PID 20960) exited with exit code 1
2019-09-10 16:17:26.732 EEST [17544] LOG:  shutting down
2019-09-10 16:17:26.898 EEST [14320] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

**EDIT:** When I try to execute `pg_ctl start -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data`,

I get this error:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because LIBPQ.dll was not found.
Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libiconv-2.dll was not
found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

I do have postgres in windows path

**EDIT2:** I ended up reinstalling the PostgreSQL server. Now I got it working again. The source of the original problem was probably that pgAgent was installed in a folder where already existing postgre files were

Comment: What do you get in the log if you run `pg_ctl start -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data`?

Comment: This only shows the shutdown, not a failed attempt to start it again.  Does your database start automatically upon reboot?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe See my edit above for the error messages i get. The files do exsist and I have postgres in system path variable

Comment: @jjanes No, it does not start on reboot. No matter what I do, those log rows that I have above, are the last thing that postgres has responded to

Comment: Perhaps those shared libraries are not on the `PATH`, or the user doesn't have permissions to access them.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  `LIBPQ.dll` is on 2 locations `1. %\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\bin` and   `2. %\PostgreSQL\11\lib` . And then `libiconv-2.dll` is in `%\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\bin`. The `pg_ctl.exe` is in `%\PostgreSQL\11\bin`. I have addad all these folders separetly to system PATH. I opened the command line window as an administrator. Still, it so strange when everything worked just fine before, but after 1 addon install, everything stoped working

Comment: Put `%\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\bin` *after* `%\PostgreSQL\11\lib` in the `PATH`. looks like the server is pulling the wrong `libpq.dll`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Well nothing worked for me. more and more errors popped up about dll files missing. Luckily I had the database backed up, so I reinstalled entire postgre. Now I got it working again. I now realize what went wrong; When I installed the pgAgent, I was supposed to chose an empty folder to be installed in. However, the first time I selected a folder with existing postgre files, so the installation probaly overwrote some files.